# 'Installing' Cisco SSL VPN license on 891 IS Router

Tags: ssl-vpn

This is a 'what if' question to get me prepared for a job I might have to do in 2 weeks time.

I support a charity that has a Cisco 891 Integrated Services router. It's (apparently) able to support SSL-VPN's with the correct license. There is a 10 user license available which my 'client' (is it a client if you dont get paid? :) is happy to purchase.

My question is. How do I 'install' such a license? All the configuration I've done on this router has been via console. It looks like the GUI config tools from Cisco are expensive or only included with costly support contracts.

Any thoughts or guidance is appreciated.